# MENUEX resource statement converted back to MENU

Tags: visual-studio-2008, mfc

In order to add IDs to POPUP statements, I need to declare the menu as MENUEX.  Unfortunately, each time I save the edited the menu using the VS2008 resource editor, it automatically converts it back to MENU and removes every MENUEX related functionality.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: What is the difference between a `MENU` and a `MENUEX`?

Comment: @sergiol: Very little really except that MenuEx does support a couple of additional menu types - MFT_RADIOCHECK and MFT_RIGHTORDER. It also allows HelpIds.

Comment: By the way, in recent versions of Visual Studio, the Resource Editor has also the annoying habit of also removing `MFT_MENUBREAK` and  `MFT_MENUBARBREAK`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually edited resources should be placed in the *.rc2 file. Visual Studio always overwrites the contents of the *.rc file.

Comment: Really? Interesting, I didn't know that.